# more scanf in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C, and `scanf` don't save my name.

```
int main() {
    char nome[12], sexo;
    int idade;
    float altura;

    printf("Cadastro!\n");
    printf("Digite seu nome :\n");
    scanf("%s", &nome);
    printf("Digite M para Masculino ou F para Feminino :\n");
    scanf("%s", &sexo);
    printf("Digite sua Idade :\n");
    scanf("%i", &idade);
    printf("Difite sua Altura :\n");
    scanf("%f", &altura);
    printf("\nOlá %s.\n", nome);
    printf("Sua idade é : %i\nSeu Sexo é : %c\nSua Altura é : %f", idade, sexo, altura);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
Olá .
Sua idade é : 19
Seu Sexo é : M
Sua Altura é : 1,750000
```

Comment: I don't speak French. I can already identify some errors, but for starters can you tell me what nome, sexo, idade, and altura are supposed to be?

Comment: It's Portuguese. Nome means name. Sexo means gender or sex. Idade means age. Altura means height.

Comment: haha ok, Dev-C++ compiled everything wrong, I took my code and put it in an online compiler and it worked !!, well ... now I will download Code::Blocks ahaha

Comment: If you no longer need help, then post your own answer and close this out, please.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Dev-C ++ did not compile my code correctly, solution: I uninstalled Dev-C ++

Comment: Good move. You might want to install a linux virtual machine you you can learn C in its native environment: a unix system :)

Comment: You also have another problem: `scanf("%s", &sexo);` should be `scanf(" %c", &sexo);` to read a single `char` after skipping any white space, including the pending newline left in `stdin` by the previous call to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at char nome[12], sexo;
there you defined one array to have 12 values and the other just a 1*1 array.

but then you asked for
scanf("%s", &nome);
and
scanf("%s", &sexo);

Sexo is a char, you should use %c not %s. %s will make C think your inputting a string. Try with %c and see if that works! everything else if fine.